# Debug message in Android Makefile

Tags: makefile, android-source

Because I've got problems with files that are not copied to their target anymore I want to debug the Android makefile.

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
# Define rules to copy PRODUCT_COPY_FILES defined by the product.
# PRODUCT_COPY_FILES contains words like <source file>:<dest file>.
# <dest file> is relative to $(PRODUCT_OUT), so it should look like,
# e.g., "system/etc/file.xml".
# The filter part means "only eval the copy-one-file rule if this
# src:dest pair is the first one to match %:dest"
$(foreach cf,$(PRODUCT_COPY_FILES), \
  $(eval _src := $(call word-colon,1,$(cf))) \
  $(eval _dest := $(call word-colon,2,$(cf))) \
  $(eval _fulldest := $(call append-path,$(PRODUCT_OUT),$(_dest))) \
  $(if $(filter $(_src):$(_dest),$(firstword $(filter %:$(_dest),$(PRODUCT_COPY_FILES)))), \
    $(eval $(call copy-one-file,$(_src),$(_fulldest))),) \
  $(eval ALL_DEFAULT_INSTALLED_MODULES += $(_fulldest)) \
 )
```

My aim is to view `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` before the loop starts, but what is the right syntax? However every try results in error messages. The whole Makefile can be found here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/Makefile

Answer (score 2):

This will probably do it:

```
$(info $(PRODUCT_COPY_FILES))
```